# Merging lists of IEnumerable type using a common attribute's value

Tags: c#, list, ienumerable

I have 6 `IEnumerable<SalesSummaryDAO>` type lists.
SalesSummaryDAO is like below,

```
  public class SalesSummaryDAO {

    public int Year {get;set;}

    public decimal? Cost {get;set;}

}
```

Here the lists are ;

```
        IEnumerable<SalesSummaryDAO> FabricCost = getFabricCostDataByYear();
        IEnumerable<SalesSummaryDAO> AccessoryCost = getAccessoryCostDataByYear();
        IEnumerable<SalesSummaryDAO> FOBRevenue = getFobRevenueDataByYear();
        IEnumerable<SalesSummaryDAO> StockCost = getStockLotsCostDataByYear();
        IEnumerable<SalesSummaryDAO> StockRevenue = getStockLotsRevenueDataByYear();
        IEnumerable<SalesSummaryDAO> FixedCost = getFixedCost();
```

As you can see each list contains a set of objects of SalesSummaryDAO type. What I need to do is, I want to calculate Net Profit for each and every year using those lists. As an example, for 2015 net profit is calculated like below :

NetProfit (2015) = FOBRevenue(2015) + StockRevenue(2015) - FabricCost(2015) - AccessoryCost(2015) - StockCost(2015) - FixedCost(2015)

After calculating the net profit for each year I want to store them in another `IEnumerable<SalesSummaryDAO>` list, where cost variable holds the net profit for each year.

Comment: You have lists, you have formula so what is your question exactly? I suppose you want to use only one list for this data instead of six lists. am i correct?

Comment: @ChitanyaGadkari Seems like you have not understood the problem clearly. Anyway I found the solution thanks to the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a grouping:

```
var resultList = FabricCost.Concat(AccessoryCost)  // append together
                           .Concat(FOBRevenue)     // append together
                           .Concat(StockCost)      // append together
                           .Concat(StockRevenue)   // append together
                           .Concat(FixedCost)      // append together 
                           .GroupBy(x => x.Year)   // group by year
                           .Select(g => new SalesSummaryDAO ()
                            {
                              Year = g.Key,
                              Cost = g.Sum(x => x.Cost)
                            }) // project to SalesSummaryDAO 
                           .ToList(); // make it a real list!
```

This would group all your list by year and sum them up- just make the items you want to subtract have negative costs (e.g. fabric costs).